# Running a timerTrigger function locally returns "Error calling the functions host: Unauthorized"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a timerTrigger function that works fine in Azure but when running it locally it returns "Error calling the functions host: Unauthorized".
What is wrong ? How can I run a time trigger locally ?

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 30 8 * * 1"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Executing it within Visual Studio Code (or command line)

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Projects\reporting-function> func run .\MyFunction\
Error calling the functions host: Unauthorized
PS C:\Projects\reporting-function>
```

Answer (score 6):

We investigated, and it is a bug in the Functions CLI. The issue is understood, and there is a [pull request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/pull/1463/files) for it.

The fix will be in the next build.